# How can I detect if the hardware buttons are disabled via guided access in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app requests that users manually enter a `Guided Access` session. Is there a way, using public `API`s, that I can detect when the home button is disabled via manually entering a guided access session and then concurrently, when it is enabled again?

Comment: I can't really think of a single good reason why you would want users to enter guided access - it would just hurt the usability of the app.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII It is a test taking app, it enhances the usability. The problem is that I can't just use c Configuration Profile to request a Guided Access Session pragmatically because it requires a supervised device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this! Guided Access guarantees that the home button is disabled so this will work for that. There is still no way to detect the lock button.

```
NSLog(@"Accessibility enabled: %@", UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled() ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```